# Triggering an animation on a gameobject with a collider2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation, platformer

I'm creating platforms that break on trigger. The animation works and the colliders are set like they should, but I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the "stepBreak" animation I have.

---

This is what I have, so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class breakablePlatforms : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject steps;
    private Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            animator.Play("stepBreak")
        }
    }
}
```

---

These are my animations and transitions:

[image: Transition from "stepIdle" to "stepBreak"]

[image: Transition from "stepBreak" to "stepIdle"]

Comment: Welcome to GameDev. You will notice I have converted your code to text; for future questions, this is preferable, as it allows users to quickly test anything. I have also removed an image, as I felt it greatly detracted from your question, and did not offer anything important. What your asking is fairly easy, I should be able to post a solution in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bool value on your animation state, you have to use the `SetBool` method.

Basically it´s playing stepIdle over and over and waiting for a if statement, **if break is true play stepBreak** and **if break is false go back to play stepIdle**

```
// play anim
animator.SetBool("break", true);

// exit anim and go back to idle state
animator.SetBool("break", false);
```

Here is a link to description https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html

Comment: All right I'll give that a shot and get back at yah. Thanks

Comment: Please accept answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to trigger animations by code is to set up a trigger, set it as the condition for the transition, and trigger it with `animator.SetTrigger()`.

---

### Setting up a Trigger

Looking at the Animator window, you should see a tabbed window to the left of the controller chart. Select the *"Parameters"* tab. Click on the button marked *+* and select *"Trigger"*. Give it a meaningful name, and your done.

[image: After selecting "Animator > Parameters > + > Trigger", I name my trigger "twitch".]

If you are missing the *"Layers / Parameters"* window, check for a closed eyelid ([image: The "Layers / Parameters" window may be folded up; click on the closed eyelid to make it display.]), along the same bar. Clicking this button unfolds the window.

---

### Setting up the Transition

On the transition to the desired animation, in your case *"stepBreak"* and in my case *"twitch*", you will find the trigger you made listed under the *"Conditions"* option. Select your trigger, and set it as the only condition.

[image: Viewing the desired transition in the Inspector, set the trigger as the only condition.]

Depending on your circumstance, you probably want to set up a transition in the opposite direction. Given that you are animating something being broken, I would assume you probably wouldn't transition back to the mended state. Either way, you can set (or not set) your additional transitions up however you want.

---

### Triggering the Trigger

Now everything is set up, all you need to do is grab a reference to the specific `Animator` instance attached to the game object, and call `animator.SetTrigger(triggerName)` where `triggerName` is the name you gave to the trigger you just created and set up.

I've done mine using the `UnityEditor` namespace to give me a quick and easy button to click from the Inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class TriggerAnimator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Reference to the Animator, which I add from the Inspector.
    public Animator animator;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(TriggerAnimator))]
public class TriggerAnimatorEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector()
        TriggerAnimator triggerAnimator = (TriggerAnimator)target;

        // If the created button "Animate" is clicked,
        if (GUILayout.Button("Animate"))
        {
            // Set off the trigger "twitch" on the animator in triggerAnimator.
            triggerAnimator.animator.SetTrigger("twitch");
        }
    }
}
```

You would probably use something more simple, like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("stepBreak")
    }
}
```

---

That's all there really is to it.

[image: With one line of code, my button animates my sprite.]